# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried some way to find `NULL` values in the column `S` but it gives the same error. What can I do?

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

```
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN S is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS nvarchar) NumberOfNullS

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN S is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS [Number Of Null Values]
FROM dbo.T

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.T
WHERE S IS NULL
```

Comment: You seem to have added random TAGs; MySQL <> SQL Server; is your issue specifically to do with JDBC driver? Magnetic ink character recognition??

Comment: Post enough information to reproduce the problem:  the actual table definition and actual, runnable queries. The first line isn't a valid query. The third query doesn't have any type conversions. The second is too expensive but doesn't have any conversions either. Is `S` a computed column perhaps? One that tries to convert a text field to a number, or compare a text field with a number?

Comment: Please don't undo all the good work that members of the community did in editing your post to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have more than 2,147,483,647 `NULL` values in your column `S`. The value you are `SUM`ming (`1`) is a `int` and so if you have too many rows it overflows. Either switch to `COUNT_BIG` (as `COUNT` returns an `int`) or continue to use `SUM` and `CAST`/`CONVERT` the `1` to a `bigint`. I personally would use `COUNT_BIG`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT_BIG(1) AS [Number Of Null Values]
FROM dbo.T
WHERE S IS NULL
```

I also use the predicate in the `WHERE`, as depending on your `INDEX`es, this should be more performant.

Comment: ...and a filtered index would let you get the count from sys.partitions without ever having to count rows yourself. (See [Bad habits : Counting rows the hard way](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way).)

Comment: That should be an even faster solution, @AaronBertrand . Wish you could post it. :( Though if this is a "one off" process, it's probably not worth the time of building such an index, but it would be if it's something that they are likely to need again (frequently) into the future.